# Selecting in GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query

```
select YEAR(t1.date) as 'year'
, MONTHNAME(t1.date) as 'month'
, COUNT(*) as total
, if (t1.Sex = 1, 'male','female') as sex
from outpatients t1
where YEAR(t1.date) = 2015 
group by MONTH(t1.date), t1.Sex
order by t1.date, t1.Sex
```

So the output will look like this:

### [image]

I would like to write a query to see female and male as the columns.
So the output will look like.

### [image]

I can't find the way to group the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUM function to sum the male and female

```
select YEAR(t1.date) as year, MONTHNAME(t1.date) as month, COUNT(*) as total
, SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS male
, SUM(CASE WHEN sex = 'female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS female
from outpatients t1
where YEAR(t1.date) = 2015 
group by MONTH(t1.date), t1.Sex
order by t1.date, t1.Sex
```

Comment: 1) YEAR(date) = 2015 is not SARGable 2) If OP removes `WHERE` clause then year can be any value (should be added to group by expression)